# Xdebug not working in VSCode Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, xdebug

I installed Xdebug and checked with `phpinfo()`.

I tried debugging `public/index.php` with "Launch currently open script" option and it worked fine.

Defining a route for testing, a controller, I started the "Listen for Xdebug" option, and then, I went to that url in my browser. But nothing happens at the preselected breakpoint.

#### launch.json

```
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "log": true
        },
```

#### xdebug.ini

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug_remote.log
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_port = 9003
```

- PHP 7.2
- Laravel 5.6
- Ubuntu 20.04
- Xdebug 3.1.2

Comment: Seems like you're using an old configuration. Check https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide on how to upgrade the options

Answer (score 3):

You are using Xdebug 3.1.2. but all your settings are still for Xdebug 2. There is a handy [upgrade guide](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide) that you most definitely should read. To replicate the Xdebug 2 settings from above with Xdebug 3 settings, use:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so

xdebug.start_with_request=yes
;xdebug.remote_autostart = 1

xdebug.mode=develop,debug
;xdebug.remote_enable = 1

; This one has been removed:
;xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp

; These are defaults, so you don't need to set them. They aso have been renamed:
;xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
;xdebug.remote_port = 9003
;xdebug.remote_mode = req

xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug_remote.log
;xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug_remote.log
```

Or in short:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug_remote.log
```